# Show the smallest value for several conditions in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a function that would show the smallest value for a given set A,B,.... and a subset of X,Y,.... I would like to represent this in the form of a table (red in the screenshot). I tried to write a function, which works, but only for one set.

```
=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$16,C2:C16))
```

when adding AND shows a value of 0 (in green)

```
=MIN(IF(AND($A$2:$A$16=L2,$B$2:$B$16=M2),$C$2:$C$16))
```

Do you have any ideas on how this can be solved?

This is an example, because the target sheet has +10k row

[image: example]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when adding AND shows a value of 0 (in green)

`AND` in your formula reduces the whole formula to one row, you can see intermediate steps of calculation by evaluating your formula.

You can use this formuala instead:
`=MIN(IF(($A$2:$A$16=L2)*($B$2:$B$16=M2),$C$2:$C$16))`

Or, somewhat easier to read:
`=MIN(FILTER($C$2:$C$16,($A$2:$A$16=L2)*($B$2:$B$16=M2)))`